# Identify Network of Wireless Packet

Tags: packet, sniffing

When sniffing wireless packets from multiple networks, how do you tell which network a packet belongs to?

---

The best guess I have right now is that you need to see the handshakes and get the mac addr from the Ethernet frame. This seems inconvenient

Comment: A packet has a source and destination address. Is this not sufficient enough to determine which network the packet comes from?

Comment: I don't think it would work for local networks with their own private addresses.

Comment: I hope you are not sniffing networks that don't belong to you. But, if your network consists of multiple subnets, it is relatively easy to determine where packets are going. The MAC address of a host has nothing to do with what network it is attached to. Maybe I am misunderstanding the question

Comment: It's pretty much easy to see everything (including Ethernet Farme) related to a packet in [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) tool. Have you tried it ?

Comment: Moloch is also a great alternative to wireshark. A bit more visually pleasing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are worth a read:

- https://wiki.wireshark.org/Wi-Fi
- https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN

Some network cards will provide 802.11 headers (including the `SSID` which you can use to identify the network), other network cards strip those and present WiFi as regular Ethernet.

Comment: I'm not having much luck getting 802.11 headers with my environment, so it may be an issue with the network card. Those sources were useful, I didn't realize it was limited to only one channel either.